# DatePicker selects selections even if binded property has not been set

Tags: xamarin.forms

I got my `DatePicker`. I check if new comming date is `equal or greater` than `SelectedOrder.TargetDate.Date`.
The check itself is fine and not allow if `coindition` is not match, nevertheless what `user` selects on `calendar` it stay in `calendar`. Why `calendar` sets user's selection even if `SelectedTargetDate` was not changed?

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding SelectedTargetDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


public DateTime SelectedTargetDate
        {
            get =>  _selectedTargetDate;
            set
            {
                if (SelectedOrder == null) return;      //on program run first time it's null
                if (value.Date < SelectedOrder.TargetDate.Date)
                    _pageService.DisplayAlert("Ostrzeżenie", "New date cannot be older than TargetDate", "ok", "cancel");
                else
                    SetValue(ref _selectedTargetDate, value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, do you want to keep the `SelectedOrder.TargetDate` if the condition is not satisfied ?

If yes,you could let your model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and change like below:

```
public class YourModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DateTime SelectedTargetDate
    {
        get => _selectedTargetDate;
        set
        {
            if (SelectedOrder == null) return;      //on program run first time it's null
            if (value.Date < SelectedOrder.Date)
            {
                _pageService.DisplayAlert("Ostrzeżenie", "New date cannot be older than TargetDate", "ok", "cancel");
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedTargetDate = value;
            }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedTargetDate"));
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: I already implement INotifyPropertyChanged and _selectedTargetDate is changed only if condition is passed - this part is fully working. The problem is even if cindition is not passed means when it goes to the part where _pageService.DisplayAlert is raised - means it doesn't set _selectedTargetDate to new value (not goes to _selectedTargetDate = value) BUT on the gui (datepicker calendar) new selection is set anyway. That's what i do not understand.

Comment: @Arie Because you miss `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedTargetDate"));` to refresh the `SelectedTargetDate` like above.It will display the date you select in the calendar,if you bind the `Date to`  `SelectedTargetDate`,you should update it every time when you select a date.

Comment: you were right i need to call propertychanged even if it was not updated. I didin't think that calendar sets the date even if property changes was not raised. Can you just explains me this behaviur? TO me logically is when no binded property was changed no new date entered by user should stay in calenadar.

Comment: @Arie You could try to bind Date to a fixed time,when you select date in the calenadar,it will also change to the new date.